# USB doesn't appear in jfilechooser

Tags: usb, jfilechooser

I want to upload files from phone device/USB by Jfilechooser
but the phone device doesn't appear in open dialoge
any body help me please
thanks million

Comment: yes the device is shown in my computer and I can copy files from it to other hard drive

Comment: but Jfilechooser open dialog only appears hard drive thers is no phone device

Comment: What OS is this on? On a *nix* like environment, a mounted drive is going to be mounted into the filesystem, so there are no "drives". For example, on Mac OS X, my phone shows up under Macintosh HD/Volumes/NO_NAME.

Comment: OS is windows , when connect phone device to laptop, I need to upload file from phone device to database using Jfilechooser but I can't because no phone device shown in open dialog filechooser